bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)

npm update
npm install bigint-buffer
npm rebuild
npm run build
npm run anchor-test


This question is similar to: bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?) when importing Connection from @solana/web3.js. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

switch to 2.0 version, its been fixed there

Version 2.0 eliminates userspace implementations of Ed25519 cryptography, large number polyfills, and more, in favour of custom implementations or the use of native JavaScript features, reducing the size of the library. It has no third-party dependencies.

